# Eagle Layout. Via sizes changes when DRU is run

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

When I run a DRU check I see that the via size changes on the board. I would like to know what part of DRU settings relates to this. Here is the animated gif showing this problem.

**BEFORE:**
[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

You can see the vias get a bit larger. It is more obvious  [in this GIF ANIMATION OF THE ISSUE](https://giphy.com/gifs/26tP96HpJ9zXdBoS4)

Comment: Check vias minimum size in DRC

Comment: @Triak can you put that as an answer so I can mart it as solution.

Comment: add your own answer and accept it, since I don't have Eagle to answer the question as it needs to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @triak suggested, the DRC rule for minimum visa size is responsible for this.
setting a lower value solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

The default rules message that pops up in the animated GIF should be a big clue as to what is going on here.

It would appear that the default values for via settings are being applied over what you have placed in the design. You should follow the advice of that warning dialog and  set the defaults as appropriate to your design and save it under a project specific set of defaults.